# How to know where is the issue in android coding

Tags: android

I am new in android and i have assigned a project.I am facing problem to find issue while going through error log.Here is my error log please tell me what is this issue and how it could be resolved

```
03-13 12:40:06.470: E/WindowManager(923): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity  om.example.mytest.ReadContactsActivity has leaked window   com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{40d0e768 V.E..... R.....ID 0,0-97,92} that was originally added here
03-13 12:40:06.470: E/WindowManager(923):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:354)
03-13 12:40:06.470: E/WindowManager(923):   at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:216)
03-13 12:40:06.470: E/WindowManager(923):   at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:69)
03-13 12:40:06.470: E/WindowManager(923):   at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:281)
03-13 12:40:06.470: E/WindowManager(923):   at com.example.mytest.ReadContactsActivity$CountDownTask.onPreExecute(ReadContactsActivity.java:50)
03-13 12:40:06.470: E/WindowManager(923):   at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:586)
03-13 12:40:06.470: E/WindowManager(923):   at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:534)
03-13 12:40:06.470: E/WindowManager(923):   at com.example.mytest.ReadContactsActivity.onCreate(ReadContactsActivity.java:34)
03-13 12:40:06.470: E/WindowManager(923):   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
03-13 12:40:06.470: E/WindowManager(923):   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
03-13 12:40:06.470: E/WindowManager(923):   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
03-13 12:40:06.470: E/WindowManager(923):   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
03-13 12:40:06.470: E/WindowManager(923):   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
03-13 12:40:06.470: E/WindowManager(923):   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
03-13 12:40:06.470: E/WindowManager(923):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-13 12:40:06.470: E/WindowManager(923):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-13 12:40:06.470: E/WindowManager(923):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
03-13 12:40:06.470: E/WindowManager(923):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-13 12:40:06.470: E/WindowManager(923):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-13 12:40:06.470: E/WindowManager(923):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
03-13 12:40:06.470: E/WindowManager(923):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
03-13 12:40:06.470: E/WindowManager(923):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Here is the code which i wrote to achieve

```
 private class CountDownTask extends AsyncTask<Void, String, Void>{


    // A callback method executed on UI thread on starting the task
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // Getting reference to the TextView tv_counter of the layout activity_main
        dialog = new Dialog(ReadContactsActivity.this);
        dialog.setCancelable(false);
        dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.progressdialog);

        progressBar = (ProgressBar) dialog.findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
        dialog.show();


    }

    // A callback method executed on non UI thread, invoked after 
    // onPreExecute method if exists

    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
         ContentResolver cr = ReadContactsActivity.this.getContentResolver();
         Cursor cur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,
                null, null, null, null);

         if (cur.getCount() > 0) {
             while (cur.moveToNext()) {
                 String id = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
                 String name = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
                 if (Integer.parseInt(cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER))) > 0) {
                     Cursor pCur = cr.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,null,
                                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID +" = ?",
                                            new String[]{id}, null);
                     while (pCur.moveToNext()) {
                           String phone = pCur.getString(
                                  pCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
                           objItem = new listBean();
                        objItem.setName(name);
                        objItem.setNumber(phone);
                        listArray.add(objItem);
                     }
                     pCur.close();
                     }
                 }
             }
        return null;
    }


    // A callback method executed on UI thread, invoked by the publishProgress() 
    // from doInBackground() method
    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) {

    }


    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        dialog.dismiss();
        objAdapter = new listAdapter(ReadContactsActivity.this, items);
        listView.setAdapter(objAdapter);

        }
```

Comment: you should look into code first or use magic orb ...

Comment: Please check this line . at com.example.mytest.ReadContactsActivity$CountDownTask.onPreExecute(ReadContactsActivity.java:50)

Comment: show your this ReadContactsActivity for better understand!!!

Comment: @Selvin: As i already told that i am new in this technology so i have not a very good knowledge in this

Comment: the error is i guess in ReadContactsActivity, line 50.. but you have to post code of that activity...

Comment: Can post the code of `onPreExecute()` method ?

Comment: @MarkoNiciforovic here is the code

Comment: what is on line number 50 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to know where is the issue in android coding ?

You always find your **activity name in logcat with line number** if there is an error in your activity code.

Answer (score 1):

Do not write the code of dismissing dialog on main thread. keep it on runOnUIThread as below:

> ```
>  @Override
>    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
>       runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
>                 @Override
>                public void run() {
>                       dialog.dismiss();
>             }
>      objAdapter = new listAdapter(ReadContactsActivity.this, items);
>      listView.setAdapter(objAdapter);
>     }
> ```